# Assign values from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database table with parent child relationships between different rows.
1 parent can have any number of children.
Children do not have children.
I want to copy 'Message' from 'Parent Category' to child categories.

```
CategoryID   Name           Value       Message      ParentID     DeptId
1            Books          9           Specials                  1
2            Music          7                                     1
3            Paperback      25                       1            1
4            PDFs           26                       1            2
5            CDs            35                       2            1
```

If that was sample data, Paperback should have Specials as it's Message after the query is run.
I have gotten the child rows (the query runs very slow, don't know why), but how do I get the data and assign it to appropriate child rows?

```
--@DeptId = 1
select * from Categories
where ParentID in(
select CategoryID from Categories 
where DeptID = @DeptId
)
```

I would like to see a solution that would not use cursors.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JOIN` across two copies of the table as child & parent should do the job (and I'm fairly sure this is valid in SQL Server).  It looks for non-NULL `ParentID` on the child table and copies `Message` from the associated `ParentID` row.

```
UPDATE c
  SET c.Message = p.Message
FROM
  Categories c
  INNER JOIN Categories p ON c.ParentID = p.CategoryID
WHERE 
  c.ParentID IS NOT NULL
  AND c.DeptID = @DeptID
```

Comment: The approach is correct, however for sql server, you should change your first few lines to: Update c FROM Categories c INNER JOIN .....

Comment: @jlnorsworthy From my [reading of the syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx), this should be valid: `UPDATE alias SET col=val FROM tbl,tbl,tbl...`

Comment: yeah you are right - fixed one syntax error only to introduce another. I'm going to blame the inability to format a comment :)

Comment: 1. Columns to update must not be prefixed with table names/aliases in SQL Server (i.e. it should be `Message = ...`, not `c.Message = ...`. 2. The "second" `SET` clause should obviously not be there. 3. The `c.Parent IS NOT NULL` test is redundant (if it is NULL, the row gets eliminated by the join condition).

Comment: Second set clause removed. (not noticed after a copy/paste operation)